# Having difficulty displaying 3 column structure

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-grid

I'm currently trying to display cards into a 3 column structure (3 cards on the first row, and then it wraps to 3 on the next row...) Also, I'm not sure why my ul is not taking the entire width of its parent. Currently, I'm trying to use the grid system.

```css
.roll-card-body{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.roll-card-body a{
    width: 100%;
}

.roll-card-body ul{
    width: inherit;
}


.roll-card-body .card{
    background: #FFF2D7;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows:auto;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='roll-card-body'>
    <ul>
        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/original.png" alt="">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/strawberry.png" alt="">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/strawberry.png" alt="">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/strawberry.png" alt="">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. UL can only contain li as direct children.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.roll-card-body` elements width is set to 80%. Your `ul` element's width is set to inherit. `.roll-card-body` is the parent element of `ul` so `ul` will also have a width of 80% of its container, ie it will inherit its width from its parent. Remove `width: inherit;` from `ul` and it will be the same width as `.roll-card-body.`

As for your grid. It is not working because you specified `display: grid` in the wrong location. At the moment it is in the `.card` class which is the class for the child elements. It should only be in the `.roll-card-body` class, that way it will be applied to all of the child elements.

Try doing something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="roll-card-body">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="images/original.png" alt="">
        <h4>Original Roll</h4>
        <p>$3/roll</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="images/original.png" alt="">
        <h4>Original Roll</h4>
        <p>$3/roll</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="images/original.png" alt="">
        <h4>Original Roll</h4>
        <p>$3/roll</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="images/original.png" alt="">
        <h4>Original Roll</h4>
        <p>$3/roll</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.roll-card-body{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

This will give you a good starting off point for creating a functional CSS grid.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the ul element right, ang having it `width: inherit` will inherit the 80% width from its parent.

So I removed ul element, and styled the li with `list-style-type: none;` to remove the bullet form.

```css
.roll-card-body{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.roll-card-body .card{
    background: #FFF2D7;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows:auto;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='roll-card-body'>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/original.png" alt="Image here">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li><h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <img src="images/strawberry.png" alt="Image here">
                
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/strawberry.png" alt="Image here">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

        <a class='card' href="">
            <li>
                <img src="images/strawberry.png" alt="Image here">
                <h4>Original Roll</h4>
                <p>$3/roll</p>
            </li>
        </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `display: flex`. It is much simpler and easier.

**BEFORE**

```css
ul {
}

li{
}

.roll-card-body .card{
    background: #FFF2D7;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows:auto;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

**AFTER**

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
}

a {
    background: #FFF2D7;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```